# Google OAuth2 using Python 3 to access YouTube API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm having trouble doing just about anything in OAuth2 using Python. I've gone through about 20 different iterations of example code from multiple sites and none of them work. Here is what I have in my file at this very moment but it doesn't compile. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient

client_id = "xxx"
client_secret = "yyy"
authorization_base_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
token_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
project_id = 'zzz'
redirect_uri = "http://localhost"

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python) as reference as it's compatible with Python 2.6 or greater.

Don't forget, you need a local webserver to test this so it can connect to internet. You can use something like

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```